# Images inserted in a question using Chrome on Android via the image uploader are always placed at the end of the question

Tags: bug, images, uploader, android, mobile-chrome

Images inserted in a question using Chrome on Android via the image uploader are  always placed at the end of the question, instead of being placed where the cursor was when clicking on the "add picture" button.

For example, if the current cursor is placed at the beginning of the post as shown below:

[image]

When the user  clicks on the "add picture" button, the picture is added at the end of the post:

[image]

Comment: Getting downvoted for reporting a bug, that's how I know I am on Stack Exchange.